# PHP script not receiving posted JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having trouble with the following JavaScript, where data is a JavaScript object:

```
var ajax_send = function(data) {
        var httpRequest;

        makeRequest('/prototype/test.php', data);

        function makeRequest(url, data) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) {
                    try {
                        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } 
                    catch (e) {}
                }
            }

            if (!httpRequest) {
                alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
                return false;
            }

            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
            httpRequest.open('POST', url);
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }

        function alertContents() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                    alert(httpRequest.responseText);
                } else {
                    alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The PHP is:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$obj = json_decode($data);
echo $obj;
```

In dev tools the request payload *looks* ok but it doesn't seem to be what the PHP is looking for. Nothing gets through to the PHP script and the response is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is impossible to tell what the PHP is looking for since you didn't show us the PHP code.

Comment: Share with us prototype/test.php page codes please

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: Not directly related, but using jquery to do ajax calls is quite a lot nicer imo.

Comment: Damn, I forgot the "no use jQuery replies"! You're right of course, it is much easier and nicer. This is a learning exercise for me as much as anything else and I like to understand the vanilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send POST requests with `Content-Type: application/json`, things work a bit differently with PHP.

You are going to need to access it like so:

```
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Instead of the usual `$_POST`.

If you want to send it as a regular form that will be populated to `$_POST`, you need to set your header like so:

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

And populate your fields like so:

```
key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

etc

Comment: I updated the answer, try setting the request header differently. You'll see how the data looks then. Also, what does your error say exactly?

Comment: Yep, that works, thank you very much :) I would still be interested in knowing how to post JSON without converting to form values though.

Comment: If you could tell me more in detail about your error, I can help you figure out why it's not working. Did you try look at the contents of `file_get_contents('php://input')` before trying to parse it?

Comment: Hmm. Not much details on the error, just 500 internal server error. The contents of `file_get_content('php://input')` is valid JSON though.

Comment: Ok, things go wrong when I use the `json_decode()` function. Is this likely to be a localhost setup problem?

Comment: Nope, it's a my PHP skills problem.  `json_decode()` needs two parameters in my version of PHP.

Comment: Is the valid JSON a string type? Can you run it through JSONLint.com and see if anything is odd with it? json_decode should work out of the box. Check your PHP logs, if you're on Unix this should be placed at /var/logs/apache2/error.log if you hadn't moved it, if you're on Windows I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah I see, that's odd, the extra parameters should be optional. If you don't set the 2nd one to true though, you will end up with an object and not an array, if that matters to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On Symfony you can use `$request->getContent();` which internally makes `file_get_contents('php://input')`). Then decode the result.

```php
$requestData = $request->getContent(); // this makes file_get_contents('php://input')
$data = json_decode($requestData, true);
```